# VBA - save workbook and add today's date to current workbook name

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

The code below shows my save macro. Right now it saves the current workbook in a specific file path with the current workbook name. How can I add today's date in the current workbook name? So it saves to the designated file path with the current workbook name and today's date on the end?

```
Sub Save_Workbook()
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "H:\HR\Cole G\Timehseet Test Path\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: use
"& Format(Now, "yyyymmdd")"
after activeworkbook.name
You can change the date format as per your need

Comment: @Srijan But how would I add it to the file name so it's before the extension?

Comment: @Srijan that will give file extension and then date since `ActiveWorkBook.Name` includes extension

Comment: so are you saying that the `Activeworkbook.Name` **already** has a previous date in it?

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= left$(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5)& Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsm"

and if you are not sure about the length of extension for example .xlsx or .xls then use "InStr" or "InStrRev" in place of Len

Comment: Use FSO and [GetBaseName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/getbasename-method)

Comment: Don't assume that the extension is 4 letters (+1 = 5).  Instead find the last "." and go from there.  There is no need to use the FSO, it's a much larger hammer then is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, `.Name` may or may not include a file extension, depending on if the file has been saved or not.  (eg. "Test.xls" or "Book2")

```
Const Path = "H:\HR\Cole G\Timehseet Test Path\"
Dim Pos as Long

Pos = InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1
' If there wasn't a ".", then the file doesn't have an extension and Pos = -1
If Pos < 0 then Pos = Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
' Now put everything together, including the file extension...
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name,Pos) & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") & Mid(ActiveWorkbook.Name,Pos+1)
```

Comment: More elegant than mine :)

Comment: there is no need to declare `Dim FileName as String`

Comment: How can i save the file in "xlsx"-Format and not in "xlsm". Because after runing the code the saving file will be saved as mxls! but i wanna have in xlsx!? any solution?

Comment: @Jsmoka Just specify the XlFileFormat value that you want.  In your case use `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbook`

Answer (score 1):

This should be reliable regardless of file extension (even if there is no file extension!), as long as you're using common Excel file types. If you're opening weird .HTML files it may need some tweaking.

```
Sub Save_Workbook()
    Dim fileNameWithoutExtension as String
    fileNameWithoutExtension = getFileNameWithoutExtension(ActiveWorkbook)
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "H:\HR\Cole G\Timehseet Test Path\" & fileNameWithoutExtension & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD"), FileFormat:=ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat
End Sub

Function getFileNameWithoutExtension(wb As Workbook)
Dim baseName As String

If (wb.Name = wb.FullName) Then
    ' This handles files that have not been saved, which won't have an extension
    baseName = wb.Name
    GoTo EarlyExit
End If

Select Case wb.FileFormat
    Case xlOpenXMLAddIn, xlOpenXMLStrictWorkbook, xlOpenXMLTemplate, xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled, _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, xlWorkbookDefault
        ' These all have a 4-character extension
        baseName = Left(wb.Name, Len(wb.Name) - 5)
    Case Else
        ' almost every other file type is a 3-character extension,
        ' but modify if needed based on this enumeration:
        ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlfileformat-enumeration-excel
        baseName = Left(wb.Name, Len(wb.Name) - 4)
End Select

EarlyExit:
getFileNameWithoutExtension = baseName

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the info!